# Horizontal ScrollView in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I created a scroll view in corona sdk,but i have some problem with it i need it only to scroll horizontally. Any Help?

```
local widget = require("widget")

local rect1 = display.newRect(20,100,150,100)
local rect2 = display.newRect(200,100,150,100)
local rect3 = display.newRect(380,100,150,100)
local rect4 = display.newRect(580,100,150,100)
local rect5 = display.newRect(780,100,150,100)

local scrollView = widget.newScrollView{ left = 0, width = 0, height = 200, }

scrollView:insert(rect1);
scrollView:insert(rect2);
scrollView:insert(rect3);
scrollView:insert(rect4);
scrollView:insert(rect5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Corona SDK API](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html), you can do the following :

```
scrollView.verticalScrollDisabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks i have done like this and it works                                                                                   'local scrollView = widget.newScrollView{ left = 0, width = 0, height = 200, verticalScrollDisabled = true,}'

Answer (score 2):

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView{ left = 0, width = 0, height = 200, verticalScrollDisabled = true,}
```